Error during a wikidata update, Blazegraph not working
I followed the instructions at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Docker to install wikibase docker. But when I run /runUpdate.sh inside wbdocker-wdqs-1 container, I get errors. I get exceptions when I /runBlazegraph.sh too. The blazegraph does not seem to run on port 9999.
/wdqs# /runUpdate.sh
wait-for-it.sh: waiting 300 seconds for wikihost:80
wait-for-it.sh: wikihost:80 is available after 0 seconds
wait-for-it.sh: waiting 300 seconds for wdqs.svc:9999
wait-for-it.sh: wdqs.svc:9999 is available after 0 seconds
Updating via http://wdqs.svc:9999/bigdata/namespace/wdq/sparql
#logback.classic pattern: %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
14:53:43.536 [main] INFO  org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.Update - Starting Updater 0.3.137 (1ac054ca5bfa49a6f743c581decf5c9be649f455)
14:53:44.353 [main] INFO  o.w.q.r.t.change.ChangeSourceContext - Checking where we left off
14:53:44.353 [main] INFO  o.w.query.rdf.tool.rdf.RdfRepository - Checking for left off time from the updater
14:53:44.569 [main] INFO  o.w.query.rdf.tool.rdf.RdfRepository - Found left off time from the updater
14:53:44.569 [main] INFO  o.w.q.r.t.change.ChangeSourceContext - Found start time in the RDF store: 2024-05-22T22:15:39Z
14:53:44.740 [main] INFO  o.w.q.r.t.change.RecentChangesPoller - Got no real changes
14:53:44.822 [main] INFO  org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.Updater - Polled up to 2024-05-22T22:15:39Z at (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) updates per second and (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) milliseconds per second
14:53:44.849 [main] INFO  o.w.q.r.t.change.RecentChangesPoller - Got no real changes
14:53:44.849 [main] INFO  org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.Updater - Sleeping for 10 secs
14:53:54.871 [main] INFO  o.w.q.r.t.change.RecentChangesPoller - Got no real changes
14:53:54.871 [main] INFO  org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.Updater - Sleeping for 10 secs
14:54:04.904 [main] INFO  o.w.q.r.t.change.RecentChangesPoller - Got no real changes
14:54:04.904 [main] INFO  org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.Updater - Sleeping for 10 secs
14:54:14.908 [main] ERROR org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.Update - Error during updater run.
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
        at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.wikibase.WikibaseRepository.fetchRecentChanges(WikibaseRepository.java:248)
        at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.change.RecentChangesPoller.doFetchRecentChanges(RecentChangesPoller.java:325)
        at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.change.RecentChangesPoller.fetchRecentChanges(RecentChangesPoller.java:314)
        at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.change.RecentChangesPoller.batch(RecentChangesPoller.java:338)
        at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.change.RecentChangesPoller.nextBatch(RecentChangesPoller.java:167)
        at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.change.RecentChangesPoller.nextBatch(RecentChangesPoller.java:38)
        at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.Updater.nextBatch(Updater.java:371)
        at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.Updater.run(Updater.java:163)
        at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.Update.run(Update.java:174)
        at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.Update.main(Update.java:98)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1804)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:693)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:591)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2630)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:832)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:729)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4141)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4000)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3070)
        at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.wikibase.WikibaseRepository.getJson(WikibaseRepository.java:441)
        at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.wikibase.WikibaseRepository.fetchRecentChanges(WikibaseRepository.java:242)
        ... 9 common frames omitted
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
        at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.wikibase.WikibaseRepository.fetchRecentChanges(WikibaseRepository.java:248)
        at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.change.RecentChangesPoller.doFetchRecentChanges(RecentChangesPoller.java:325)
        at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.change.RecentChangesPoller.fetchRecentChanges(RecentChangesPoller.java:314)
        at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.change.RecentChangesPoller.batch(RecentChangesPoller.java:338)
        at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.change.RecentChangesPoller.nextBatch(RecentChangesPoller.java:167)
        at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.change.RecentChangesPoller.nextBatch(RecentChangesPoller.java:38)
        at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.Updater.nextBatch(Updater.java:371)
        at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.Updater.run(Updater.java:163)
        at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.Update.run(Update.java:174)
        at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.Update.main(Update.java:98)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: (org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1804)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:693)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:591)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2630)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:832)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:729)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4141)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4000)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3070)
        at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.wikibase.WikibaseRepository.getJson(WikibaseRepository.java:441)
        at org.wikidata.query.rdf.tool.wikibase.WikibaseRepository.fetchRecentChanges(WikibaseRepository.java:242)
        ... 9 more

What does this error mean?
